Access Instagram user's basic info like profile photo, id by just entering the username
I am working on a site where i want to access Instagram user's basic info like profile photo, id by just entering the username. How can i do it? I already have a basic display API integrated.
i tried using graph api and an unofficial api for instagram.

I would've recommended the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/, but the basic display API is going to be shut down in two days  So, instead, you have to use the normal API using an Instagram business account.

can i achieve this goal by normal API using an Instagram business account? what are the challenges?

Yes, you can. Here are the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-platform/instagram-api-with-instagram-login
